# Make Angular Material tabs drag/drop re-order tab index

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, frontend, user-experience

Is there any way to make Angular Material tabs drag/drop, re-order the tab index using:
CDK drag-drop service

[CDK Drag-Drop - Service](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#services)

Or any other possible clean workaround there?

regards